# how to expand expression string in powershell

Tags: powershell, string-interpolation, variable-expansion

is there any comlet like expand-string?

```
$a="ab cd"
$command = 'dir $a'
Write-Host (expand-string $command)
```

expected:

```
dir abcd
```

Note, I know I can just use `$command="dir $a"` to expand the string, but that was not I want to, I need to save the string `dir $a` as a *literal* in a variable and expand it *later* in a command.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? not "expand a doublly-embedded string" ... WHY are you wanting to do that? there may be other ways to do it ... [*grin*] ///// have you looked into using a scriptblock instead of a string? if that doesn't work for you, perhaps `Invoke-Command` would work - it RUNS the string instead of simply expanding it.

Comment: `$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($Command)`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/53797850/45375