# placing get-content into array for html email

Tags: html, powershell, string-interpolation, variable-expansion

Html portion

```
$html = @($htm)

$html = @"

<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<body>
text
$computername
$username
text
</body>
</html>
"@

 $html | out-file c:\scripts\temp\Report.html
```

I have html language in the $html variable.  When I decide to change the HTML code I need to go back into the PowerShell script.  I'd rather just have the html in a separate file.  How can I use get-content to place the contents of separate file into the `$html = @"..."@` variable.
I am using powershell $variables in the html portion to make dynamic emails!

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for *string templating*, i.e. the ability to expand a string with placeholders on demand, based on the then-current values that the placeholders (variables) represent.

PowerShell offers such a feature via the (little-known) [`.InvokeCommand.ExpandString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.commandinvocationintrinsics.expandstring#system-management-automation-commandinvocationintrinsics-expandstring(system-string)) method of the [automatic `$ExecutionContext` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#executioncontext), which treats a string value *as if it were* an [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings), i.e. performs *string interpolation on it*:

- Save your HTML template string via a [*verbatim* string (`'...'`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings), i.e., a *single*-quoted one, so as to prevent *instant* expansion of embedded variable references such as `$computer`:

```bash
# Note the use of *single* quotes, to ensure
# that $computername and $username *aren't* expanded.
@'
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<body>
text
$computername
$username
text
</body>
</html>
'@ | Out-File c:\scripts\temp\Report.html
```

- Then use the template as follows:

```bash
# Read the template in full (-Raw)
$htmlTemplate = Get-Content -Raw c:\scripts\temp\Report.html

# Perform sample instantiations of the template.
1..2 | ForEach-Object {
  # Set the variable values to use in the template.
  $computername = "computer$_"
  $username = "user$_"
  # Now instantiate the template
  $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($htmlTemplate)
  "---`n" 
}
```

This outputs the following - note how `$computer` and `$username` were expanded to the then-current values of these variables:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<body>
text
computer1
user1
text
</body>
</html>

---

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<body>
text
computer2
user2
text
</body>
</html>

---
```

**Caveat**:

- The above assumes that you either *fully control* or *implicitly trust* the content of your HTML template file, given that it is possible to inject arbitrary *commands* into the template, using `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--)
- See below for a way to prevent expansion of subexpressions.

---

###### Preventing expansion of subexpressions (`$(...)`), to prevent code injection:

- The following variation ensures that any (unescaped) `$(...)` sequences are *exempt* from expansion, i.e. they are *retained verbatim*.
- This is achieved by `` ` ``-escaping the `$` in every `$(` sequence, but *only if that `$` isn't already escaped*. It is the latter requirement that requires the nontrivial [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) below. In a nutshell, the `$` in `$(` must only be escaped if it is either preceded by *no* or an *even number* of `` ` `` chars. (the latter form a sequence of *escaped escape characters*, which implies that the following `$` is *unescaped*). For an explanation of the regex and the option to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/QqIsLl/2).

```bash
# Read the template in full (-Raw) and escape the $ of unescaped
# $( sequences with ` (backtick), which will prevent expansion of any
# $(...) subexpressions.
$htmlTemplate = 
  (Get-Content -Raw t.html) -replace '(?<!`)((?:``)*)\$\(', '$1`$$('

# Perform sample instantiations of the template.
1..2 | ForEach-Object {
  # Set the variable values to use in the template.
  $computername = "computer$_"
  $username = "user2"
  # Now instantiate the template.
  $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($htmlTemplate)
  "---`n" 
}
```

Comment: this is definitively the better way. About code injection, you can add something like this `if ($htmlTemplate  -match "\$\(.+\)") {throw "This template contains possible arbitrary code"}` right after reading the template. Obsiously, this cannot be done if your template needs such code...

Comment: Thanks, @CFou, but instead of a warning it may be simpler to simply _suppress_ expansion of what would otherwise be subexpressions. Please see my update.

Answer (score 0):

Dependent on your use case, a simple string replacement might work:

```
# read the content of the file
[string]$html = Get-Content `
    -Path 'c:\path\to\template.html' `
    -Encoding 'UTF8' `
    -Raw;

# replace the strings
$html = $html.Replace('$computername', $computername);
$html = $html.Replace('$username', $username);

# write the result to the output file
$html | Out-File 'c:\path\to\report.html';
```

Comment: Your answer is perfectly right and easy to remember matches between the html code and the variables. However, I find this way `[String]::Format((Get-Content 'c:\path\to\template.html' -Raw), $computername, $username) | Out-File 'c:\path\to\report.html'` with replacing `$computername` by `{0}` and `$username` by `{1}` into the html code, more elegant - but this is only a matter of taste :)

Comment: Any ideas to make dynamic?  I have 40 variables to fill.

Comment: @iceman you might want to store the variables in a dictionary and then iterate over the entries in the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have a HTML template where several variables need to be inserted, I would rather use a structured CSV file than a simple text file to read the variable values needed.

Lets say your csv file looks like this:

```
"ComputerName","UserName"
"PC0123","Roger Rabbit"
"PC8769","Daffy Duck"
"PC5544","Yosemite Sam"
```

Option 1: Use a HTML template with numeric placeholders to use with the `-f` Format operator

```
$html = @"
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<body>
text
{0}
{1}
text
</body>
</html>
"@
```

Then use like

```
Import-Csv -Path 'X:\Somewhere\UsersAndComputers.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    # replace the placeholder strings {0} and {1} etc. with values from the csv
    $newHtml = $html -f $_.ComputerName, $_.UserName
    # create a path and filename for the filled-in html
    $newFile = 'C:\scripts\temp\Report_{0}.html' -f $_.UserName
    # write the file
    $newHtml | Set-Content -Path $newFile -Encoding UTF8
}
```

Option 2: Use a HTML template with string placeholders to use with `.Replace()` or `-replace`

```
$html = @"
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<body>
text
@@COMPUTERNAME@@
@@USERNAME@@
text
</body>
</html>
"@


Import-Csv -Path 'X:\Somewhere\UsersAndComputers.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    # replace the placeholder strings with values from the csv
    $newHtml = $html.Replace('@@COMPUTERNAME@@', $_.ComputerName).Replace('@@USERNAME@@', $_.UserName)
    # create a path and filename for the filled-in html
    $newFile = 'C:\scripts\temp\Report_{0}.html' -f $_.UserName
    # write the file
    $newHtml | Set-Content -Path $newFile -Encoding UTF8
}
```

Note:
Instead of the string `.Replace()` method you could also use `-replace` or `-creplace` regex operators like

```
    $newHtml = $html -replace '@@COMPUTERNAME@@', $_.ComputerName -replace '@@USERNAME@@', $_.UserName
```

where `-replace` is a case-insensitive operator. If you need it to work case-sensitively, then use `-creplace`

When you need to insert many variables, option 1 would be my preferred way..